# Angular - Cannot read property 'sort' of null

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using a sort method for some data and as I understand, the sort is "activated" before the actual data comes in and although it works, it leaves some error in the console: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null.`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let attendee of (listOfAttendees$ | async | sort:'lastName': 'firstName':'asc')">
    <div class="attendees-list__item d-flex">
        <div class="attendees-list__item-name course-details-attendees col-4 col-md-4 text text-cooler-grey align-self-center pl-3">
          {{ attendee?.lastName }}, {{ attendee?.firstName }}
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Is there any good place where I can move the sort function so it does not give the `null` output?

Comment: how you are defining listOfAttendees$ ...?

Comment: From what I understand `listOfAttendees$` is an Observable since you also use the `async` pipe. My guess is that in the creation of the `listOfAttendees$` observable you have not initialized it (empty array works) and you are trying to sort something null, hence the error.  Might be wrong, a stackblitz example could help.

Comment: The sort works fine, but I get the error in the console, I am going to try to edit the observable as suggested to see if it works.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu Have you found a solution to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to edit the observable so that you do not have to sort inside the template

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  listOfAttendees$: Observable<Attendant[]>;
  sortedAttendees$ = this.listOfAttendees$.pipe(
    map(attendees => attendees ? attendees.sort((a, b) => {
      const lastname = a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName);
      return lastname === 0 ? a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName) : lastname;
    }) : null)
  )
}
```

and in your template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let attendee of sortedAttendees$ | async">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the observable?
If so you could emit an empty array instead of a null value.
That should prevent the TypeError.